# Adding a public getter, private setter to a TypeScript prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add a property, let's call it "features", to the HTMLElement prototype in TypeScript. It can init as null, and it needs to be restricted to a particular class in my codebase (called FeatureManager). That's all quite easy. What I'm struggling with, and I'm not very well-versed in JS/TS, is setting up the new property so it has a public getter, but a private setter. Basically I want the setup to be that I call a new method on any given HTMLElement to setup the features object, and then that HTMLElement has the same features object for the page's lifetime, I don't want it to be overridden except maybe by an internal HTMLElement method. How do I set this up?

So normally it's easy, like:

```
class HTMLElementPlus {
    private _features: FeatureManager;

    public get features() {
        return this._features;
    }

    private set features(features: FeatureManager) {
        this._features = features;
    }
}
```

But the issue I'm having is how do I get the same public getter, private setter for an extension onto an existing prototype?

So I can easily add:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    features: FeatureManager;
}
```

But how do I apply a private setter to this within the prototype?

Comment: Could you share some of your code (or pseudo-code) so that we can easily imagine what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: TS has variant accessors so you should be able to make the setter `private` and the getter `public`, but without a [mre] that demonstrates your issue it’s hard for us to make specific suggestions that will be applicable to your situation. Could you [edit] to provide one? Preferably something we can paste into our own IDEs and immediately see what you’re talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it needs to be restricted to a particular class in my codebase*"? `HTMLElement` is a global, and [you should not modify it!](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Comment: It is considered bad practice to mess with common native prototypes. That being said: Interfaces can't have access modifiers, and even if they could, what good would a "private" setter there do for you? Surely that would restrict your code from using it just as much as it would restrict other code from using it, since you're not writing the class. (more...)

Comment: (...continued) Instead, you could make it `readonly` in the interface. `readonly` is easy enough to overcome anyway, so you can do the writing in your own implementation however you want. Maybe [like this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wg8OBN) shows (although it would have been nice for your [mre] to actually show what you're planning to do here so I didn't have to guess).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface with only the getter:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    get features(): any
}

const a = {} as HTMLElement

a.features = 42 // Cannot assign to 'features' because it is a read-only property.(2540)
const b = a.features // No error
```

Hope that works for you.